# Count overlapping classes of numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have what I'll call a background matrix, shown below with `a` and `b` values, and then a series of mask matrices, shown below with `1` and `0` values. What I want to do is for each mask matrix, get the breakdown of which classes from the background matrix the positive values in the mask matrix would cover if it were superimposed over the background matrix.

I.e. in the below examples, for mask matrix #1 I would want to get `a:9` since all 9 values in this matrix would superimpose over `a` values in the background matrix, and for mask matrix #2 I would want `a:8, b:8` since 8 of the mask values would superimpose `a` and 8 would superimpose `b`.

```
# background
[['a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a']
 ['a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a']
 ['a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a']
 ['a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a']
 ['a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a']
 ['b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b']
 ['b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b']
 ['b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b']
 ['b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b']
 ['b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b']]

# mask 1
[[1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]

# mask 2
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Below is a brute force way of doing this, but on the large matrices (images) I really want to do this with, this approach is taking too long.

```
background = np.concatenate([np.full((5,10),"a"), np.full((5,10),"b")])
print(background)

first_mask = np.full((10,10), 0)
first_mask[0:3,0:3] = True
print(first_mask)

second_mask = np.full((10,10), 0)
second_mask[3:7,3:7] = True
print(second_mask)

# non-numpythonic, brute force approach for counting first_mask
background_map = {}
for (y,x), pixel in np.ndenumerate(first_mask):
    if pixel:
        background_class = background[y,x]
        try:
            background_map[background_class] += 1
        except KeyError:
            background_map[background_class] = 1
print(background_map)
```

How could this be done faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [numpy.unique](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to find unique elements and boolean indexing to apply mask on data.

```
print(dict(zip(*np.unique(background[first_mask.astype(bool)], return_counts=True))))
# {'a': 9}
print(dict(zip(*np.unique(background[second_mask.astype(bool)], return_counts=True))))
# {'a': 8, 'b': 8}
```

STEPS

```
In [3]: background[second_mask.astype(bool)]
Out[3]:
array(['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b',
       'b', 'b', 'b'], dtype='<U1')

In [4]: np.unique(background[second_mask.astype(bool)], return_counts=True)
Out[4]: (array(['a', 'b'], dtype='<U1'), array([8, 8]))
```